# Type assertion for non exported interface

Tags: menu, typescript, menuitem, electron, typescript-typings

I am new to Typescript so apologies if this is a simple question.

I am trying to build an application to run on Electron (http://electron.atom.io/). I have added the type declarations using typings (https://github.com/typings/typings) - using the env: electron typings.

This seems to be fine. I can now import declarations from typings as needed.

However, I am trying to create an application menu for my application. The method I would like to use is create a "template" object and use the Menu.buildFromTemplate method (http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/).

The problem I am facing is that the Type definition for the Menu.buildFromTemplate specifies:

```
static buildFromTemplate(template: MenuItemOptions[]): Menu;
```

and the MenuItemOptions interface is not exported in the definition file.

I have tried 2 things:

```
 const template = [
 {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Undo',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        role: 'undo'
      },
      {
        label: 'Redo',
        accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        role: 'redo'
     } 
    ]
  }
];

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
```

This gives me an error: " Argument of type '{ label: string; submenu: { label: string; accelerator: string; role: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MenuItemOptions[]'."

From this, I thought that I need to cast the template to MenuItemOptions. However, I can't add MenuItemOptions to the import as it's not exported in the definition.

Is this an error in the definition. Should the MenuItemOptions also be exported? Or, am I doing something wrong.

I can provide full source if needed.

Comment: `Electron` is a global. You can access the MenuItemOptions as `const template: Electron.MenuItemOptions[] = ...`

Comment: The error I get when trying your code is this:
    Types of property 'role' are incompatible.Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"undo" | "redo" | "cut" | "copy" | "paste" | "selectall" | "minimize" | "close" | "about" | "hide...'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"services"'.

Comment: @cdbajorin - I have to admit. I still don't understand the "global" thing in typings. I have read the typings documents which try to explain. Do you know of any other materials? FYI - it worked thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly typing `template` works for me

```
const template : Electron.MenuItemOptions[] = [
 {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Undo',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        role: 'undo'
      },
      {
        label: 'Redo',
        accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        role: 'redo'
     } 
    ]
  }
];

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
```

It seems to be because the `role` property is registered as type `string` which is not compatiable with type `'"undo" | "redo" | "cut" | "copy" | "paste" | "selectall" | "minimize" | "close" | "about" | "hide...'`